# Scala Lift - Reading a file from "/resources/toserve"

Tags: java, file, scala, lift

I'm attempting to provide a `StreamingResponse` for files stored under Lifts resources/toserve directory, in order to authorize access for different users.

I can access an image for example with:

localhost:8080/classpath/images/test.jpg

But when I try and actually read the file using scala I keep getting file not found exceptions:

```
val file = new java.io.FileInputStream("/classpath/images/test.jpg")
```

Is there a specific method to reading files located on classpath?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

To read resources from the toserve-directory you need to do a call like

```
LiftRules.getResource("/toserve/images/test.jpg")
```

If you try to use 'classpath' instead of 'toserve' you will receive an empty box.

By default, Lift uses two different path-prefixes to locate resources either programmatically within the server or through a link-element from HTML. For the former, you will use the 'toserve'-prefix, for the latter the 'classpath'-prefix.

This behavior is specified in the objects net.liftweb.http.LiftRules and net.liftweb.http.ResourceServer. In particular, you can there specify (i.e. replace) the path to the resources. The relevant code is:

```
/** (from net.liftweb.http.ResourceServer)
 * The base package for serving resources.  This way, resource names can't be spoofed
 */
var baseResourceLocation = "toserve"
```

You might also want to look at the following method in LiftRules, which allows you to redefine the name used to serve resources through the server:

```
/** (from net.liftweb.http.LiftRules)
 * The path to handle served resources
 */
@volatile var resourceServerPath = "classpath"
```

If you wish to use the same prefix to refer both to resources you can use either (or both) of these settings to achieve your purpose.

Comment: Just in case someone still uses lift these days... If you want your own resources to be served by /classpath/, don't forget to whitelist them via `ResourceServer.allowedPaths`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
LiftRules.getResource("/classpath/images/test.jpg")
```

That should return a java.net.URL to the item you are looking for.

This may also have more information on what you are looking to do: http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#lst:streaming-download